# Could not get unknown property ‘classesDir’ android studio

Tags: android, gradle

please help me getting error?

```
  Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.
 Open File
```

I Codes

```
    task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-get-unknown-property-classesdir-for-main-classes/30591/15) issue

> SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir() was deprecated in Gradle 4 and removed in Gradle 5. Please use getClassesDirs() in Gradle 5

In your instance, the problem is with

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
```

Change it to

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
```

Also, you can omit most of the `files(...)` calls in your task definition as most of the `Jar` tasks methods accept `Object`. Eg:

```
task dist(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
    from sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from project.assetsDir

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
```